# Which Function Substitutes htmlspecialchars() For Arrays?

Tags: php, html, mysql

## Q.) Which Function Substitutes `htmlspecialchars()` For Arrays?

*I'm working on a small app for adding tables to a db, printing them via html and allowing for these tables to be deleted via a hidden form button.*

### I only receive error for `?addjoke`.

> Error is on line #19 of HTML File. I marked line 19 with comment tags above and below.
>
> > I also attached PHP Controller below HTML code block for reference. The `$jokes` array lies below "// ***** Display DB ***** //."

I just changed selecting just one table to two tables and I had to change my `mysqli_fetch_array` code from just calling the `joketext` table (for just printing the rows) to `joketext` AND `id` (`id` for deleting `joketext` - the functionality that caused this problem to arise.)

**So this code:**

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $jokes[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['joketext']); // Changed from just $row['joketext'] to now both tables.
}
```

**has forced me to change:**

```
<p><li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($joke, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> -
```

**to:**

```
<p><li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($joke['text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> -
```

Which I understand is in fact an array because there's no other way to call both without it right? I'm a newbie so I don't understand why `htmlspecialchars()` can only be used with strings...what am I missing?

## HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>List of Jokes</title>
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
             <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Slabo+27px">
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="mainContainer">
                <div id="contentContainer">

                    <div class="headerItem">Here are all the jokes in the database:</div>

                    <div id="addJoke">+ <a href="?addjoke">Add Joke</a></div>

                    <ol>
                        <?php foreach ($jokes as $joke): ?>
                            // ***** LINE***** 19 //
                            <form action="?deletejoke" method="post">
                            // ***** LINE***** 19 //
                                <p><li><?php echo htmlspecialchars($joke['text'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); ?> - 
                                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $joke['id']; ?>">
                                <input type="submit" value="Delete"></li></p>
                            </form>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ol>

                </div>


                <div id="footer">
                    <p><a href="/php/day%207%20code/before/addjoke/">IDJB Home</a>  -  <a href="?addjoke">Add Joke to IDJB</a>  -  <a href="#">Sitemap</a></p>
                    <p>&copy; <?php echo date("Y") ?> Internet Joke Database</p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

## PHP Controller File

```
<?php

// ***** MagicQuoteFix ***** //

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())  
{  
  function stripslashes_deep($value)  
  {  
    $value = is_array($value) ?  
        array_map('stripslashes_deep', $value) :  
        stripslashes($value);  
    return $value;  
  }  
  $_POST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_POST);  
  $_GET = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_GET);  
  $_COOKIE = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_COOKIE);  
  $_REQUEST = array_map('stripslashes_deep', $_REQUEST);  
} 

// ***** Begin Connection Info ***** //

$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'ijdbuser', 'ijdbpw');

if (!$connection)
{
    $error = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8'))
{
    $output = 'Unable to set database connection encoding.';
    include 'output.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (!mysqli_select_db($connection, 'ijdb'))
{
    $error = 'Unable to locate the joke database.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

// ***** Display DB ***** //

$result = mysqli_query($connection, 'SELECT id, joketext FROM joke');

if (!$result)
{
    $error = 'Error fetching jokes: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $jokes[] = array('id' => $row['id'], 'text' => $row['joketext']);
}

if (isset($_GET['addjoke'])) {}

else
{
    include 'jokes.html.php';
}

// 


// ***** Begin Add/Remove DB Options ***** //

if (isset($_GET['addjoke']))
{
    include 'form.html.php';
    exit();
}

if (isset($_GET['deletejoke']))
{
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['id']);

    $sql = "DELETE FROM joke WHERE id='$id'";
    if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    {
        $error = 'Error deleting joke: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    //header('Location: .');
    exit();

}

if (isset($_POST['joketext']))
{
    $joketext = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST['joketext']);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO joke SET
        joketext="' . $_POST['joketext'] . '",
        jokedate=CURDATE()';

    if (!mysqli_query($connection, $sql))
    {
        $error = 'Error adding submitted joke: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    header('Location: .');
    exit();
}




?>
```

> I realize some of my code is old or depreciated. I started learning from an older book and I figure I'll just finish it for context with older apps before moving to more advanced OOP programming.

Thanks for helping me learn.

Comment: You also can't just simply print an array with echo.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm a newbie so I don't understand why htmlspecialchars() can only be used with strings...what am I missing?

You have to iterate through the array and escape the strings in it:

```
foreach($arr as &$v)
  $v = htmlspecialchars($v);
```

Now you have each value in the array escaped.

Comment: I'm so new I wouldn't know how to implement this. Can you copy/paste my code block and revise this post if you have time so I can learn the format? I have no idea why this Learnable.com Tutorial by Kevin Yank is wrong. I tripple-tripple checked his code reference and he has exactly what has given me this error.